# How to configure a Maven plugin with classpath resource?

Tags: maven

Today I configure the Maven war plugin like this :

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
   <webXml>${basedir}/../common/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
</configuration>
```

This allows me to share that web.xml between several projects.
The problem with this approach is that my Maven project is not self contained. It depends on a relative path on the file system.

Is it somehow possible to do something like this ? :

```
   <webXml>classpath:com/mycompany/common/web.xml</webXml>
```

And of course, make that file available on the classpath of the plugin.

Thanks

Comment: you can use absolute path like "D:\dev"

Comment: Try adding the file location under build/resources                 <build>
  <resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>...</directory>
   </resource>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to create a dedicated Maven module with packaging type `jar` containing the `web.xml`. Let's call it com.mycompany:common.

> Is it somehow possible to do something like this ? :
>
> ```
> <webXml>classpath:com/mycompany/common/web.xml</webXml>
> ```

Have you tried i.e. you know for sure that it doesn't work? If it did I suppose you'd have to use a leading '/' (/com/...).

> And of course, make that file available on the classpath of the
>   plugin.

That'd be easy then...just add a dependency to com.mycompany:common to make it available in the classpath. Of course it'd have to be available in your Maven repository.

If `classpath:` doesn't work, I'm really not sure anymore myself, you could use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to unpack `web.xml` from the JAR in order to make it available to the `maven-war-plugin`.

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unpack-web-xml</id>
      <phase>..any phase before packaging..</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <outputDirectory>...dir you'll use for the war plugin later...</outputDirectory>
            <includes>/com/mycompany/common/web.xml</includes>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, I could make it with the dependency plugin. NB: The classpath: does not work (at least for the war plugin), it tries to find it on the file system anyway.